# Azure Devops AgentPools Access Denied to perform this action: Administer Permissions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2020

I Have Azure DevOps on-prem Version Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.1

I have a project collection administrator privilege.

when I try to create a new agent pool or add an agent to the current agent pool I get an error that says

> Access denied. Ahmed A. Sobeeh needs Manage permissions to perform
> the action. For more information, contact the Azure DevOps Server
> administrator.

if I tried to add myself as admin on the agent pool security git the below error

> Access Denied:
> System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity;S-1-5-21-2315945116-4195333612-642830686-21480
> needs the following permission(s) on the resource AgentPools to
> perform this action: Administer Permissions

- I added my user as a project collection administrator privilege.
- I tried to add myself as admin on the agent pool security git the below error

> Access Denied:
> System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity;S-1-5-21-2315945116-4195333612-642830686-21480
> needs the following permission(s) on the resource AgentPools to
> perform this action: Administer Permissions

Comment: Someone probably changed the permissions on that pool. Can you see who currently does have permissions?

Comment: there is no permissions on the agent pool and i cannot add my user there as getting an error of 

 Access Denied: System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity;S-1-5-21-2315945116-4195333612-642830686-21480 needs the following permission(s) on the resource AgentPools to perform this action: Administer Permissions


and i am already collection admin

Comment: There is an Agent pool Administrator permission. That is seperate from collection admin. I'm not sure if you can get yourself back in after being locked out.

Comment: Try explicitly adding yourself to the collections 'Build Administrators' group.

Comment: You can also check if the access level of the account in Access Levels. If the access level is stakeholder, you can change to grant the basic access level to the account and check if it can work

Comment: Thanks @jessehouwing for your support, Yes i know that there is separated permission for the agent pool, but as collection admin, i have the permission to add myself as admin in that agent pool, am i right?

Comment: I know @KevinLu-MSFt but actually there is another issue in the access level page :D

i am getting error 404 if I try to open the access level page.

but my user is newly created and then assigned collection admin privi to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I found that the solution to this problem was to add my Active Directory (AD) account, the one I use to log in, as a Windows Server admin on the machine itself.

This step resolved the permission issues, and I was then able to add myself as an agentpool admin and then create agent pools and add agents without encountering any access-denied errors.

I hope this solution helps others facing a similar problem. If you have any questions or need further clarification, feel free to ask.